# MegaCli: Get the /dev/sd* device name for a logical drive

Tags: linux, megaraid

Let's say I know the drive I want is on Adapter 8, Virtual Drive 0, is there a way to get the Linux device name (e.g. `/dev/sdt`)? I am on RHEL 6.2.

`-pdlist`displays a WWN value for each physical drive, but that doesn't help much. `-ldinfo` doesn't print a WWN or any other identifying value.

```
# ./MegaCli64 -pdlist -a8 | grep WWN
WWN: 500051610003776C
WWN: 5000516100037BFC
WWN: 5000516100038090
WWN: 50005161000284F4
WWN: 5000516100037C0C
WWN: 5000516100037C5C
WWN: 50005161000310C8
WWN: 5000516100037F4C

# ls -1dt /dev/disk/by-id/wwn*
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd142c12c84d
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd142c0973e6
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd132c002573
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd122bf6e2f6
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd122beda52a
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd112be46f10
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd112bdb3ffb
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600605b0043e52d01721fd102bd20f14

# ./MegaCli64 -v                       
 MegaCLI SAS RAID Management Tool  Ver 8.03.08 Mar 15, 2012
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to compare the disk serial number from `-pdlist` with the output from `lshw`.

```
# MegaCLI -pdlist -a0 | grep "Inquiry Data:"
Inquiry Data:       XXXXXXXXXXXXHitachi YYYYYYYY                 ZZZZZZ
...
```

Then search the output of `lshw` for the serial number. The device name will be in the `logical name` field.

I can't verify this because all of my disks are in a volume.

## Identifying Logical Drives

Compare the `Target Id` from MegaCLI with the scsi bus target for the device. In `lshw` it is `bus info`.

```
# MegaCli -ldinfo -Lall -aall 


Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 7.275 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 6
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy       : Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disabled
Ongoing Progresses:
  Check Consistency        : Completed 17%, Taken 89 min.
Encryption Type     : None


Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 7.275 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 6
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy       : Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disabled
Ongoing Progresses:
  Check Consistency        : Completed 17%, Taken 89 min.
Encryption Type     : None
```

From lshw:

```
# lshw -class disk
...
              *-enclosure UNCLAIMED
               description: SCSI Enclosure
               product: Bobcat
               vendor: LSI CORP
               physical id: 1.75.0
               bus info: scsi@0:1.117.0
               version: 0504
               configuration: ansiversion=5
          *-disk:0
               description: SCSI Disk
               product: MR9260-16i
               vendor: LSI
               physical id: 2.0.0
               bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0
               logical name: /dev/sda
               version: 2.12
               serial: svDASJ-f8kM-4qp5-BswW-3IKC-DDyA-djz8N7
               size: 7450GiB
               capacity: 7450GiB
               capabilities: lvm2
               configuration: ansiversion=5
          *-disk:1
               description: SCSI Disk
               product: MR9260-16i
               vendor: LSI
               physical id: 2.1.0
               bus info: scsi@0:2.1.0
               logical name: /dev/sdb
               version: 2.12
               serial: NHUvUy-1tm4-aGYW-g6DZ-t1Z9-gxW8-JhvFfL
               size: 7450GiB
               capacity: 7450GiB
               capabilities: lvm2
               configuration: ansiversion=5
```

Comment: I just tried this, but I have IBM drives and for me it looks like there's no correlation between the serial number that shows up in `-pdlist` and the serial number that shows up `lshw`. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It may be that your controller card is not exposing the real serial number and makes a volume serial number for each disk.

Comment: I should add this is a JBOD setup with each drive configured in a RAID0 array of one drive. So I would expect the physical drive's serial number to be hidden, but I'm wondering if I can get some info out of the logical drive config.

Comment: I just checked a bunch of MegaCLI options, but I couldn't find any logical drive serial numbers.

Comment: May I ask why you chose to configure each disk as a RAID 0 logical drive? You should normally be able to access each disk individually without creating logical drives.

Comment: At least with the adapters I'm using and the Linux distros I use, a drive in Unconfigured(good) state is not visible to the OS. It looks like other LSI adapters may behave differently, but I haven't looked into it too deeply.

Comment: Looks like JBOD is disabled on the adapter by default, but I can enable it: `./MegaCli64 -AdpSetProp -EnableJBOD 1 -a0`

Comment: To only show disks, use: lshw -class disk

Answer (score 10):

I just added some support to my fork of megaclisas-status for matching the logical drive to an OS Native device. Here's an example output:

```
$ sudo ./megaclisas-status
-- Controller information --
-- ID | H/W Model                  | RAM    | Temp | Firmware     
c0    | LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i   | 1024MB | 88C  | FW: 23.32.0-0009 
c1    | LSI MegaRAID SAS 9280-4i4e | 512MB  | N/A  | FW: 12.15.0-0205 

-- Array information --
-- ID | Type   |    Size |  Strpsz |   Flags | DskCache |  Status |  OS Path | InProgress   
c0u0  | RAID-1 |   1817G |  256 KB | ADRA,WT |  Enabled | Optimal | /dev/sda | None         
c0u1  | RAID-5 |  16370G |  512 KB | ADRA,WB |  Enabled | Optimal | /dev/sdb | None         
c1u0  | RAID-0 |    476G |  256 KB | ADRA,WT |  Enabled | Optimal | /dev/sdc | None         

-- Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                                  | Size     | Status          | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI Device ID
c0u0p0  | HDD  | WD-WMC300422505WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 80.00A80 | 1.817 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 31C  | [252:4]  | 17      
c0u0p1  | HDD  | WD-WMC300421817WDC WD20EFRX-68AX9N0 80.00A80 | 1.817 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 31C  | [252:5]  | 18      
c0u1p0  | HDD  | WD-WX41DA40LCE5WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1 82.00A82 | 5.456 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 32C  | [252:0]  | 15      
c0u1p1  | HDD  | WD-WX41DA40L42RWDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1 82.00A82 | 5.456 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 31C  | [252:1]  | 12      
c0u1p2  | HDD  | WD-WX61DA4HAKFZWDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1 82.00A82 | 5.456 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 32C  | [252:6]  | 14      
c0u1p3  | HDD  | WD-WX41DA40LEF1WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1 82.00A82 | 5.456 TB | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 31C  | [252:7]  | 16      
c1u0p0  | SSD  | 0000000011310344CFE3M4-CT512M4SSD2 070H      | 476.4 Gb | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | N/A  | [252:1]  | 11      

-- Unconfigured Disk information --
```

The tool itself is available at:
http://step.polymtl.ca/~coyote/dist/megaclisas-status/megaclisas-status

I hope this helps,

Vincent

Comment: This works great, even at Centos 6, thanks!

Comment: Please note that the tool was accepted and merged upstream so a more recent version is at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eLvErDe/hwraid/master/wrapper-scripts/megaclisas-status

Comment: Wow, this save me a headache. Works beautifully. Thanks

Comment: Tried that but only got numbers in os path column

Comment: Please report any issues at: https://github.com/eLvErDe/hwraid/issues

Answer (score 10):

For anyone stumbling on this question and using `storcli` (successor of `MegaCLI`), you can map a virtual drive to the disk seen by the operating system with the following:

```
$ /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/v0 show all | grep NAA
SCSI NAA Id = 6001676001750006201086de0bd7f605
$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep wwn-0x6001676001750006201086de0bd7f605
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jan 23 10:55 wwn-0x6001676001750006201086de0bd7f605 -> ../../sdk
```

Tested with `storcli-1.21.06` download at: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/1.21.06_StorCLI

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `lshw`, I think you can just use `/dev/disk/by-path` to get the relationship between the scsi target id and the logical device name(sdX).

```
targetId=0;dev=`ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep -E "scsi-[0-9]:[0-9]:${targetId}:[0-9] " | awk '{print($11)}'`; echo ${dev##*\/}
```

---

```
  deviceId=$1
  ldPdInfo=`$MegaCommand -LdPdInfo -aALL | grep -E 'Virtual Drive|Device Id'`
  if [ $ldPdInfo ]; then
    targetId=`echo $ldPdInfo | awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {while (NR) print a[NR--]}' | awk "/Device Id: ${deviceId}$/,/Virtual Drive/" | grep -Eo 'Target Id: [0-9]' | grep -Eo '[0-9]'`
    dev=`ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/ | grep -E "scsi-[0-9]:[0-9]:${targetId}:[0-9] " | awk '{print($11)}'`
  else
    wwn=`$MegaCommand -PdList -aALL | awk "/Device Id: ${deviceId}$/,/WWN/" | grep "WWN" | awk '{print($2)}'`
    # wwn=`echo "obase=16;ibase=16; $wwn-1" | bc`
    dev=`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep -i -E "wwn-0x${wwn:0:-1}[0-9a-z] " | awk '{print($11)}'`
  fi
  devName=${dev##*\/}
  echo $devName
```

Comment: Short and sweet.

Answer (score 3):

I have been dealing with this across a number of new servers recently and I've come up with a **solution**!  We are not using RAID on the "RAID" card, just using the SAS drives as JBOD.  The `/dev/disk/by-id` mappings are off by one (or a few) from the `SAS Address`.  This seems bizarre, but it works across dozens of servers I've tested it on.  I have also received [independent confirmation](https://github.com/chicks-net/megamap/issues/1) that this works for others.

[megamap](https://github.com/chicks-net/megamap) is a short Perl script that implements the discovery above.  It produces a map of Linux drive `sd*` to MegaRaid drive ID and also displays the WWN from Linux.  After using this in production for a while I also added `megablink` and `megaunblink` for controlling the "come fix me" blinking LED.  That feature has saved me from pulling the wrong drive out of the server.  Please submit bug reports on [github](https://github.com/chicks-net/megamap/issues).

[image: logo] [ image thanks to [Scott Vrable](http://scottvrable.com/) ]

Comment: I have added a utility called `megablink` to the same github repo that  will blink the _bad_ drive for the field technician to easily find it.

Comment: Based on a bug report and subsequent fixes I have released a new version of `megamap` on github.

Answer (score 2):

Harry's command was very helpful, but I needed to go a step further and determine the pci device because I have multiple SAS adapters in my configuration. Figured I should share:

```
  vdisk=1

  MegaCommand=/opt/MegaRAID/CmdTool2/CmdTool2

  vendor_id=$($MegaCommand -AdpAllInfo -aALL \
    | grep -E "^Vendor Id" \
    | sed 's/.*: //g' )

  device_id=$($MegaCommand -AdpAllInfo -aALL \
    | grep -E "^Device Id" \
    | sed 's/.*: //g' )

  pci_address=$(lspci -n \
    | grep "$vendor_id" \
    | grep "$device_id" \
    | awk '{print $1}' )

  dev_sdx=$($MegaCommand -LDInfo -LALL -aALL \
    | grep "^Virtual Drive: $vdisk (" \
    | tr -d ")" \
    | sed 's/.*Target Id: //g')

  dev_sdx=$(ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/ \
    | grep -E "$pci_address-scsi-[0-9]:[0-9]:$dev_sdx:[0-9] " \
    | grep sd  \
    | sed 's/.*\///g')

  echo "Found /dev/ as /dev/$dev_sdx"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate tool called `lsiutil` that has been discontinued. If it works for your card, it may be easier to use: http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Obsolete/Obsolete%20Common%20Files/LSIUtil_1.62.zip

Once you select your controller card, option 42 is supposed to display the OS names. I use this on Solaris, and the disks are in real JBOD mode instead of a bunch of single disk RAID 0 logical drives.

Comment: I downloaded that zip and it doesn't look like it works for my card+OS, unfortunately. Seems like I might be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching for the same thing and found this post - http://sysadm.pp.ua/linux/monitoring-systems/python-lsi-megaraid-monitoring.html . You can use python and bash script which give you all needed info:

```
root@s11:~# bash megaraid.sh log

-- Array information --
-- ID | Type   |    Size |  Strpsz | Flags | DskCache |   Status |  OS Path | InProgress
c0u0  | RAID-5 |   2725G |   64 KB | RA,WT |  Default | Degraded | /dev/sda | None
-- Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                               | Size     | Status          | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | Device ID
c0u0p2  | HDD  | SEAGATE ST1000NM0001 0002Z1N4K2PY         | 930.3 Gb | Failed          | 6.0Gb/s  | 29C  | [4:2]    | 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is very easy with StorCLI:

```
storcli /c8/v0 show all | grep "OS Drive Name"
```