# smartctl & megaraid: how to find the right device node for an adapter #

Tags: smart, megaraid, smartctl, megacli

I can list physical drives on all megaraid adapters using:

```
megacli -PDList -aALL
```

This will display an adapter # for each adapter, and then list the physical drives attached to them.

The individual devices in the PDList output also have a Device Id which is used for the smartctl command e.g. for device id 3:

```
smartctl -a -d sat+megaraid,3 /dev/sda
```

Both commands use the same device id, so no problem there. But how can we properly map the adapter # to a device node?

Running smartmontools-5.43-1.el6 on CentOS 6. Looking at the source code it seems it needs a bus number / host_no obtained from ioctl `SG_GET_SCSI_ID` or `SCSI_IOCTL_GET_BUS_NUMBER` on the named device node. Is this the same number used as "Adapter #" in MegaCLI output?

Actually in my case I could probably get away with hardcoding it to /dev/sda, but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://serverfault.com/questions/381177/megacli-get-the-dev-sd-device-name-for-a-logical-drive/567328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I've done it before. There might be better ways.

Get the PCI bus ID for the adapter from MegaCLI:

```
/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -adpgetpciinfo -a0 | grep Bus
Bus Number      : 2
```

In this case, BUS=2. 
Then look through the PCI table for devices on that BUS, and look for the 'hostX' entry:

```
ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0${BUS}\:00.0/ | grep host
host0
```

So, HOST=host0.
Now look for the target in that host directory

```
ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0${BUS}\:00.0/${HOST}/ | grep target
target0:2:0
```

Our SCSI target ID is 0:2:0  (host 0:channel 2:target 0).

Match SCSI target with the output of lsscsi

```
# lsscsi 
[0:2:0:0]    disk    LSI      MR9271-8i        3.24  /dev/sda 
[1:2:0:0]    disk    LSI      MR9271-8i        3.24  /dev/sdb 
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      INTEL SSDSC2BA80 5DV1  /dev/sdc
```

MegaCLI adapter a0 corresponds to /dev/sda (0:2:0 is ~= 0:2:0:0 in this case. The final 0 is the LUN ID)

If I follow the same method for adapter a1 I get a bus number of 3, host1, and a target value of 1:2:0, which maps to /dev/sdb.

Comment: I no longer have access to the hardware to check so I'm going to  take your word for it. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 11):

Run `smartctl --scan` to print all devices attached including the device id and RAID type:

```
# smartctl  --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
```

Another output:

```
# smartctl  --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,5 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_05], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,7 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_07], SCSI device
```

Here, `megaraid` is the RAID type and `5,7` are the device IDs

Answer (score 1):

Node can be found this way:

```
# megacli -pdlist -a0| grep 'Device Id'
Device Id: 11
Device Id: 12
# smartctl -a -d megaraid,11 /dev/sda
```